# Need Assistance with Batch File ( Game Servers )

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello everyone I wanted help with this batch file i have created from scratch. FYI I have zero coding exp.

```
@echo off
color B
echo About to start....
TIMEOUT 5
echo Killing any Servers before I start them.... 
TIMEOUT 5
taskkill /f /im Unturned.exe
echo DONE!
TIMEOUT 5
echo Starting =ZBG= servers....
TIMEOUT 5
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp1ar.lnk"
TIMEOUT 5 
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp2sn.lnk"
TIMEOUT 5
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp3ar.lnk"
TIMEOUT 5
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp4sn.lnk" 
TIMEOUT 5
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp5ar.lnk"
TIMEOUT 5
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp6sn.lnk"
TIMEOUT 8
:loop
echo **@@**DONT FORGET TO CLOSE ME**@@**
goto loop 
exit
```

So I have a Windows Server VPS that I am hosting off my hosted Dedi Box. I have six game servers for a game called "Unturned". The only way to host this many servers is to start them separately via desktop shortcut.

I really wish the `timeout` would not say "`please press any key to continue`", I tried using the `pause` or `brake` commands and I could not get it to work, It needs to have the amount of time I set in the script above so servers start clean without getting errors from them all starting at the same time.

I need the script to do the same thing but have a timer on the end to restart it every 4 hours. very simple talking about it but I don't know enough to make this happen.

Comment: Why is [tag:php], and [tag:c] tagged?

Comment: suggest using `sleep *seconds*` rather than `timeout *seconds*`

Comment: Joe - When you get a moment, can I get a status of the answer I provided here https://superuser.com/questions/1030214/need-assistance-with-an-existing-batch-file as you mentioned the solution was working great so I was curious if you'd be accepting that answer at some point or what? When you get a moment sir I'd greatly appreciate your follow up regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timeout in this way:

```vb
@timeout /T 5 /nobreak >NUL
```

must read:
in `cmd` `HELP TIMEOUT`, `HELP GOTO`, `HELP START`, and `HELP ECHO`

Here the script restart the server every 4 hours.

```vb
@echo off
color B

:loop
cls

echo About to start....

@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
echo Killing any Servers before I start them.... 

@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
taskkill /f /im Unturned.exe
echo DONE!

@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
echo Server #1 is going to start
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp1ar.lnk"

echo Server #2 is going to start
@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp2sn.lnk"

echo Server #3 is going to start
@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp3ar.lnk"

echo Server #4 is going to start
@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp4sn.lnk" 

echo Server #5 is going to start
@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp5ar.lnk"

echo Server #6 is going to start
@timeout /T 10 /nobreak >NUL
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pvp6sn.lnk"

REM Every 4 hours kill and start servers. note 1H = 3600 seconds
REM use timeout then goto loop
@timeout /T 14400 /nobreak >NUL

goto loop
```

**Note:**

1. If you want to see the countdown in the last `timeout` remove `>NUL`
2. Remove `/nobreak` if you want restart servers on demand

Comment: You might also want to look at the `stop` command as it 'should' result in a more graceful shutdown of the server

Comment: just a note: for running it periodically, a scheduled task may be a better solution (via GUI - "Task Scheduler" or command line `schtasks /create /?`)